# Why Lisesharte shown in the initial incident?

Tags: saijaku-muhai-no-bahamut

In *Saijaku Muhai no Bahamut*, Arcadia became the kingdom suffered the most from coup which was done majorly with the help of the Black Hero. But Lux was shown as the prince of Arcadia even though someone who is related to him was the Black Hero at that time.

Why in the beginning the Lisesharte was shown as being in the castle in the incident?